# Writing ROR application, trying to add Facebook "recommend" to article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, configure

General problem.  Working on a ROR app hosted on Heroku. However I am getting the error in local environment.  For Articles I wish users to be able to "recommend" the article via Facebook and display number of "recommends" the Article has recieved.
I have a ROR application on Heroku and have set up a Facebook app with minimum info.
Where/how do I add in the Facebook info he ROR application.

I have tried a number of different things including
(1) adding some info to config/environment/development e.g.

```
# Facebook stuff 
config.fb_app_id = 257669251071656
config.fb_app_secret = 7b53604575d5dc0259466cfd41808c93
```

which gives error

```
/Users/davidlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': /Volumes/F Drive/drill_investor/config/environments/development.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Should I be adding a config/initializers/facebook.rb file and/or changes in config/environments/development…production.  If so what goes into the onfig/initializers/facebook.rb file ?

At the moment I have some stuff set up for devise and paperclip in these directories - however this was all copied and haven't figured out how it actually works.

any help appreciated
Pierre

The new whole config/application.rb file, with comments removed, is below

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module  DrillInvestor
  class Application < Rails::Application

  # pmlc 
  ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true
  ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags = true
  config.fb_app_id = ENV["FACEBOOK_APP"]
  config.fb_app_secret = ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"]
  # pmlc

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `environment` files of Rails are meant to give you a place to specific environment-specific settings -- such as different asset paths, Gem settings, etc to use

---

**Error**

Your error basically says your `development.rb`file is not formatted correctly (you should post the whole file). You'll need to be able to set it out correctly - I'd even recommend putting the details into `application.rb`:

```
#config/application.rb
config.fb_app_id = ENV["FACEBOOK_APP"]
config.fb_app_secret = ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"]

#config/application.yml -> from Figaro
FACEBOOK_APP: 257669251071656
FACEBOOK_SECRET: 7b53604575d5dc0259466cfd41808c93
```

---

**Figaro**

I'd recommend using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to keep your sensitive data behind closed doors. It allows you to create [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) on both local & production environments

I think this should solve your issue, but it will definitely help to post your `development.rb`

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer Iwill be working through this today.  Some of the code in my application is "monkey see , monkey do" stuff" and I only partially understand it.